# Does Kefura red ki means something more?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball, when a fighter changes his ki color usually means a transformation. The only exception I remember for this are Vegeta's different ki colors like the lilac ki color when he makes the Galick Ho attack, or the yellow color he gets at some point when he first fought Goku, or the light blue color he got a couple of times.

[image]

Does Kefura's red ki means something more or did she just get that color because she was performing a strange attack?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Kale's ki was shown to be green in color during her transformations, when she transformed to her Berserker state and mastered LSSJ state. Also, Caulifla had a Ki base attack which was red in color. Kefla is a fusion of both Caulifla and Kale, so I wouldn't really think much of it. The colors don't really represent anything.